# Как изменить dependency property в user control'е во время нажатия на кнопку

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependencyproperty

Допустим, у нас есть user control, в котором есть dependency property под названием Percentage типа double. Значение Percentage отображается в текстблоке. Также у нас есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую должно меняться свойство Percentage. Как это лучше сделать? В моём представлении код должен выглядеть примерно вот так:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp3.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="MyControl">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=MyControl,
                                  Path=Percentage,
                                  StringFormat=N2}" />
        <Button Width="100"
                Height="50">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="MyControl"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Percentage">
                            <DoubleAnimation From="0"
                                             To="100"
                                             Duration="0:0:1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: В обработчике события Click?

Comment: @aepot , это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Событие Click запускается после того, как отпускаешь клавишу мыши. Я бы хотел узнать, как изменять свойство во время того, когда клавиша нажата и делать это плавно, в виде анимации.

Comment: Есть свойство IsMouseDirectlyOver, и если вам Click не нужен, то зачем тогда Button?

Comment: @aepot, это упрощённый вариант того что я пытаюсь сделать в другом приложении, где нужна Button. Я хочу узнать, как менять Dependency Property относящееся к всему user control'у из визуального состояния "Pressed", или триггера IsPressed=true, или ещё каким-то образом из кнопки, которая является частью этого user control'a. Это должно как-то просто делаться из xaml'a, только я не могу допереть как.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+dependencyproperty) покопайтесь, есть `TemplateBinding` или `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`.